# Are mutation rates normally distributed? If not, what are they?

Tags: genetics, evolution, mutations

On average, there are  64 mutations per generation in the human genome. Is this constant, or can we expect variation in the number of mutations?

Comment: You have posed a different question in your title and in the main text which is a bit confusing. As a short hint: Quantities that are bounded (i.e. mutation rate can only be a positive number) cannot be normally distributed. But they can be, for example, distributed by the [log-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Comment: this depends a lot on the mutation, different types of mutations have different probabilities. Its all based on the laws of chemistry.

Answer (score 2):

Mutations in this context are being treated as discrete count data (there either happen or they don't). So the number of mutations per person in a given generation should form a [discrete probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Discrete_probability_distribution). Because they are a single count variable bounded at zero (can't have negative counts) and finite (genomes don't go on forever), a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)(pwɑːsɒn/) is probably the expected best fit. A Poisson distribution can sometimes be approximated by a normal distribution when the Poisson count mean (λ) is large (some say λ>20, some say λ>100).

Answer (score 0):

Note: there are 60ish *substitutions* per generation, on average. There are probably [many times that number](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiO3O-WlL__AhX5AzQIHRIFB6sQFnoECBcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC6435258%2F&usg=AOvVaw2j9olDOgQ1_No2bjpqzY72) including all mutations (e.g. microsatellites, centromeric satellite repeats, etc). There is almost by definition a telomeric mutation on every chromosome end at every cell division, which alone is comparable to substitution number per generation.

Figure 1d of [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41588-020-0708-0/figures/1) suggests that the distribution of substitutions alone is log-normal in cancer, as suggested by the commenter.

I am not aware of a reference for distribution of other mutations.

Comment: What does log normal mean

Comment: @ShannonT The lognormal is a distribution that looks normal after a logarithmic transformation of the underlying data. For more info I'd suggest [googling it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).